# Java Defensive Copies

Tags: java, theory, defensive-programming

I've seen defensive copies coded like this

```js
void someMethod(Date d) {
    myDate = new Date( d.getTime() );
}
```

But that doesn't make sense to me, isn't there a way in Java to create an identical copy in memory of that object?

I've read the `clone()` will not work in all instances, but I don't understand why.

Answer (score 7):

I could try to answer this, but I'd just be plagiarizing Josh Bloch, so here's a link to the resource instead:

> ### [Copy Constructor versus Cloning](http://www.artima.com/intv/bloch13.html)
>
> **Bill Venners:** *In your book you recommend using a copy constructor instead of implementing `Cloneable` and writing `clone`. Could you elaborate on that?*
>
> **Josh Bloch:** If you've read the item about cloning in my book, especially if you read between the lines, you will know that I think clone is deeply broken. There are a few design flaws, the biggest of which is that the `Cloneable` interface does not have a `clone` method. And that means it simply doesn't work: making something `Cloneable` doesn't say anything about what you can do with it. Instead, it says something about what it can do internally. It says that if by calling `super.clone` repeatedly it ends up calling `Object`'s `clone` method, this method will return a field copy of the original.
>
> But it doesn't say anything about what you can do with an object that implements the `Cloneable` interface, which means that you can't do a polymorphic `clone` operation. If I have an array of `Cloneable`, you would think that I could run down that array and clone every element to make a deep copy of the array, but I can't. You cannot cast something to `Cloneable` and call the `clone` method, because `Cloneable` doesn't have a public `clone` method and neither does `Object`. If you try to cast to `Cloneable` and call the `clone` method, the compiler will say you are trying to call the protected `clone` method on object.
>
> The truth of the matter is that you don't provide any capability to your clients by implementing `Cloneable` and providing a public `clone` method other than the ability to copy. This is no better than what you get if you provide a copy operation with a different name and you don't implement `Cloneable`. That's basically what you're doing with a copy constructor. The copy constructor approach has several advantages, which I discuss in the book. One big advantage is that the copy can be made to have a different representation from the original. For example, you can copy a `LinkedList` into an `ArrayList`.
>
> `Object`'s `clone` method is very tricky. It's based on field copies, and it's "extra-linguistic." It creates an object without calling a constructor. There are no guarantees that it preserves the invariants established by the constructors. There have been lots of bugs over the years, both in and outside Sun, stemming from the fact that if you just call `super.clone` repeatedly up the chain until you have cloned an object, you have a shallow copy of the object. The clone generally shares state with the object being cloned. If that state is mutable, you don't have two independent objects. If you modify one, the other changes as well. And all of a sudden, you get random behavior.
>
> There are very few things for which I use `Cloneable` anymore. I often provide a public `clone` method on concrete classes because people expect it. I don't have abstract classes implement `Cloneable`, nor do I have interfaces extend it, because I won't place the burden of implementing `Cloneable` on all the classes that extend (or implement) the abstract class (or interface). It's a real burden, with few benefits.
>
> Doug Lea goes even further. He told me that he doesn't use `clone` anymore except to copy arrays. You should use `clone` to copy arrays, because that's generally the fastest way to do it. But Doug's types simply don't implement `Cloneable` anymore. He's given up on it. And I think that's not unreasonable.
>
> It's a shame that `Cloneable` is broken, but it happens. The original Java APIs were done very quickly under a tight deadline to meet a closing market window. The original Java team did an incredible job, but not all of the APIs are perfect. `Cloneable` is a weak spot, and I think people should be aware of its limitations.

Comment: nice link. So in few words: Using Cloneable can lead to copies with shared states.

Comment: One advantage of `clone` that Mr. Bloch doesn't mention is that if a type implements a public `clone` method which chains back to `object.clone`, then subtypes which don't add any fields that encapsulate state in mutable objects can use the inherited `clone` method without having to override it.  The proper way of implementing `clone`, assuming one's parent class has also implemented it correctly, is generally to simply chain to the parent's `clone` method and then clone any new fields which encapsulate state in mutable objects.

Comment: If any link in the chain has a broken `clone` method that uses copy constructors, then any derived class must define its own copy constructor which sets all the derived-class fields in the new instance whether they encapsulate mutable state or not.  Much ickier.

Answer (score 3):

`clone()` is only implemented meaningfully in some classes, because there are a lot of decisions involved in cloning that the JVM or the compiler doesn't make for you (e.g., shallow vs. deep copying). Some would also argue that the whole concept in Java is broken and therefore rarely used.

The end result, however, is that many classes cannot be cloned. In these cases, a user clones them by generating and initializing one object based on the other.

However, the `Date` class implements `Cloneable`, so there isn't really a benefit in this specific case compared to just using the "copy constructor".

One situation where cloning is preferable is when you are working with class hierarchies. Imagine you are representing a mathematical expression as a tree of Expression subtypes, where you reference the ***outermost*** expression.

Let's say that in this case it is a Plus. You would call clone on your reference to an Expression, but what you would really get is a new instance of Plus. With constructors you can't really do that because your Expression could be an interface or an abstract class.

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple way to make an identical copy that always works.

Clone was supposed to do that, but it is not implemented by all classes and thus more or less broken.

Another approach would be to serialize/deserialize, but serialization is also not supported by all classes.

Comment: And using serialization would be horribly inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

From a mobile code security point of view, `clone` can typically be overridden.

```
@Override public Date clone() {
    return this; // Ha!
}
```

Even if you don't care about security, you could imagine a programmer being "clever" causing a bug report in your code.

The expectation that particularly `clone` will return exactly the same runtime type also causes implementation problems.